# Exception while trying to verify a digital signature

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, verification

I run a java program to verify digital signature

```
package com.cryptography;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class VerifyDkimSignature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            //Read encoded public key bytes
            fis = new FileInputStream
                    ("/home/src/com/cryptography/DkimPublicKey");
            byte[] encKey = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(encKey);
            fis.close();

            //Generate public key
            X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

            //Read signature bytes from file
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream
                    (new FileInputStream
                            ("/home/src/com/cryptography/Signature"));
            byte[] signatureBytes = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read(signatureBytes);

          //Initialise signature instance
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(pubKey);

           //Supply signature object with the data for verification
            bis = new BufferedInputStream
                    (new FileInputStream
                          ("/home/src/com/cryptography/SampleFile.txt"));
            byte[] origFile = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while(bis.available() != 0) {
                len = bis.read(origFile);
                sig.update(origFile, 0, len);
            }

            boolean isVerifies = sig.verify(signatureBytes);
            System.out.println("Signature verifies::"+isVerifies);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I execute it, I get the following exception

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature encoding error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.cryptography.VerifyDkimSignature.main(VerifyDkimSignature.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier mismatch: 1.3.14.3.2.26
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.decodeSignature(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Can someone please explain the reason for the error?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that "1.3.14.3.2.26" (from the IOException) is the OID for a SHA-1 algorithm. So the mistake which I have done here is using different algorithms for verification and signing i.e I have used SHA1withRSA for signing and SHA256With RSA for verification. This got resolved once I changed the algorithm at the verification end to SHA1WithRSA